python inputs plugin not detecting keyboard but not printing key presses
using the python Inputs plugin to make controller and keyboard shortcuts on my windows laptop. For some reason only the inputs from the controller is working but the keyboard. It is detecting the keyboard when I run
    for device in devices:
        print(device)

but when I run
from __future__ import print_function

from inputs import get_key


def main():
    """Just print out some event infomation when keys are pressed."""
    while 1:
        events = get_key()
        if events:
            for event in events:
                print(event.ev_type, event.code, event.state)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

I get nothing, none of the buttons print a event code/state but the controller version of it does.
I have tried every line of code online that uses the "get_key" or some variation that I can retro fit into using get_key. I've tried both the built in keyboard and a USB keyboard. Is the plugin just too old at this point? Is there another method that I can use?
Many thanks.
